# Reasons cookie with samesite=none is not sent?

Tags: apache2, cookie, google-chrome, post, safari

I have a fairly high traffic service that relies on a samesite=none cookie. I have seen that this cookie is not sent for about 1% of users in a cross domain context. This is the exact case my site needs samesite=none, for a SAML POST login from another IDP -- login fails without it. I'm wondering if there are any known browser addon's or other reason the cookie may not be working for some users? I found https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198181 but I dont think thats the only cause -- the user agents are spread out more.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google's docs](https://web.dev/articles/samesite-cookies-explained), sending a `SameSite=none` requires you to include the `Secure` parameter as well or it can be rejected.

```
Set-Cookie: widget_session=abc123; SameSite=None; Secure
```

Comment: thank you for the response, i have checked, my cookie does have the secure flag